# Optimistic locking and re-try

Tags: optimistic-locking, etcd

I'm not sure about proper design of an approach.

We use **optimistic locking** using `long` incremented version placed on every entity. Each update of such entity is executed via compare-and-swap algorithm which just succeed or fail depending on whether some other client updates entity in the meantime or not. Classic optimistic locking as e.g. hibernate do.

We also need to adopt **re-trying approach**. We use `http` based storage (etcd) and it can happen that some update request is just timeouted.

And here it's the problem. How to combine optimistic locking and re-try. Here is the specific issue I'm facing.

Let say I have an entity having `version=1` and I'm trying to update it. Next version is obviously `2`. My client than executes conditional update. It's successfully executed only when the version in persistence is `1` and it's atomically updated to `version=2`. So far, so good.

Now, let say that a response for the update request does not arrive. It's impossible to say if it succeeded or not at this moment. The only thing I can do now is to **re-try the update again**. In memory entity still contains `version=1` intending to update value to `2`.

The real problem arise now. **What if the second update fails because a version in persistence is `2` and not `1`?**

There is two possible reasons:

1. first request indeed caused the update - the operation was successful but the response got lost or my client timeout, whatever. It just did not arrived but it passed
2. some other client performed the update concurrently on the background

Now I can't say what is true. Did my client update the entity or some other client did? Did the operation passed or failed?

Current approach we use just **compares** persisted entity and the entity in main memory. Either as java equal or json content equality. If they are equal, the update methods is declared as successful. I'm not satisfied with the algorithm as it's not both cheap and reasonable for me.

Another possible approach is to do not use `long` version but `timestamp` instead. Every client generates own timestamp within the update operation in the meaning that potential concurrent client would generate other in high probability. The problem for me is the probability, especially when two concurrent updates would come from same machine.

Is there any other solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can fake transactions in etcd by using a two-step protocol.

Algorithm for updating:

First phase: record the update to etcd

- add an "update-lock" node with a fairly small TTL. If it exists, wait until it disappears and try again.
- add a watchdog to your code. You MUST abort if performing the next steps takes longer than the lock's TTL (or if you fail to refresh it).
- add a "update-plan" node with [old,new] values. Its structure is up to you, but you need to ensure that the old values are copied while you hold the lock.
- add a "committed-update" node. At this point you have "atomically" updated the data.

Second phase: perform the actual update

- read the "planned-update" node and apply the changes it describes.

  - If a change fails, verify that the new value is present.
  - If it's not, you have a major problem. Bail out.
- delete the committed-update node
- delete the update-plan node
- delete the update-lock node

If you want to read consistent data:

- While there is no committed-update node, your data are OK.
- Otherwise, wait for it to get deleted.

  - Whenever committed-update is present but update-lock is not, initiate recovery.

Transaction recovery, if you find an update-plan node without a lock:

- Get the update-lock.
- if there is no committed-update node, delete the plan and release the lock.
- Otherwise, continue at "Second phase", above.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, as `etcd` is built upon HTTP which is inherently an unsecure protocol, it will be very hard to have a bullet proof solution.

Classical SQL databases use connected protocols, transactions and journalisation to allow users to make sure that a transaction as a whole will be either fully committed or fully rollbacked, even in worst case of power outage in the middle of the operation.

So if 2 operations depend on each other (money transfert from one bank account to the other) you can make sure that either both are ok or none, and  you can simply implement in the database a journal of "operations" with their status to be able to later see if a particuliar one was passed by consulting the journal, even if you were disconnected in the middle of the commit.

But I simply cannot imagine such a solution for `etcd`. So unless someone else finds a better way, you are left with two options

- use a *classical* SQL database in the backend, using `etcd` (or equivalent) as a simple cache
- accept the weaknesses of the protocol

BTW, I do not think that timestamp in lieue of long version number will strengthen the system, because in high load, the probability that two client transaction use same timestamp increases. Maybe you could try to *add* a unique id (client id or just technical uuid) to your fields, and when version is n+1 just compare the UUID that increased it : if it is yours, the transaction passed if not id did not.

But the really worse problem would arise if at the moment you can read the version, it is not at n+1 but already at n+2. If UUID is yours, you are sure your transaction passed, but if it is not nobody can say.